# Sort a list by the order of its elements occurring in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Now I have a sting consisting of factors and separators

```
String str = "result = aaa + bbb + aa + ccc + aaa";
```

and a list of the factors,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "ccc", "aa", "bbb");
```

My question is that I want to sort the list by the order of its element occurred in the string.

The separator in the string is unknown, but it won't be the same as the factor definitely.

The expected list is

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "aa", "ccc");
```

Comment: did you tried yourself using any logic?

Comment: You wrote a `Comparator` that uses the index of the substring in the full string. Report back once you tried and have concrete problems you can't solve.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (Java 9+):

```
String str = "result = aaa + bbb + aa + ccc";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "ccc", "aa", "bbb");

Map<String, Integer> wordStart = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(str).results()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MatchResult::group, MatchResult::start));
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(wordStart::get));

System.out.println(list);
```

For Java 8, replace the `results()` stream code with:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordStart = new HashMap<>();
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(str); m.find(); )
    wordStart.put(m.group(), m.start());
```

*Output*

```
[aaa, bbb, aa, ccc]
```

Basically, the code starts by building a map of the words to their starting index in the string:
`result=0, aaa=9, bbb=15, aa=21, ccc=26`

It then sorts the list by those start index values.

*Beware:* The code will throw a `NullPointerException` if the list contains a word that is not in the string. If you want unknown words to bump to the end of the list, then use:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(wordStart::get, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```